# How can I reference multiple Google Sheets worksheets from .streamlit/secrets.toml?

Tags: python, google-sheets, streamlit

I want to be able to aggregate data from multiple Google sheets spreadsheets in a single [streamlit](https://docs.streamlit.io/) application.

The documentation at [Connect Streamlit to a public Google Sheet](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/databases/public-gsheet) only shows a single spreadsheet.

```ini
# .streamlit/secrets.toml
[connections.gsheets]
spreadsheet = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxx/edit#gid=0"
```

```py
# streamlit_app.py

import streamlit as st
from streamlit_gsheets import GSheetsConnection

# Create a connection object.
conn = st.connection("gsheets", type=GSheetsConnection)

df = conn.read()

# Print results.
for row in df.itertuples():
    st.write(f"{row.name} has a :{row.pet}:")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference multiple Spreadsheets from the `.streamlit/secrets.toml` file using the following structure:

```ini
# .streamlit/secrets.toml

[connections.name_one]
type = "gsheets"
spreadsheet = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxx/edit#gid=0"

[connections.name_two]
type = "gsheets"
spreadsheet = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxx/edit#gid=0"
```

```py
# streamlit_app.py

import streamlit as st
from streamlit_gsheets import GSheetsConnection

# Create a connection object for the first spreadsheet
conn_one = st.connection("name_one", type=GSheetsConnection)
df_one = conn_one.read()


# Create a connection object for the second spreadsheet
conn_two = st.connection("name_two", type=GSheetsConnection)
df_two = conn_two.read()
```